# Grunt - Read XML File

Tags: gruntjs

I am new to grunt. I'm trying to figure out how to read an `.xml` file from a grunt task. Ideally, I'd like to load the xml into JSON. However, I can't figure out how to even read an `.xml` file from a grunt task. Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that doesn't require python or a c compiler, and is synchronous, try [node-xml-lite](https://github.com/hgourvest/node-xml-lite):

```
var parseXML = require('node-xml-lite').parseString;
var webConfigDoc = parseXML(grunt.file.read('../web.config'));
```

The parsed document object can be a little tricky to  work with, but underscore find* methods can help.

Comment: Where can I find documentation about how to use ```parseString()```?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try [grunt-convert](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-convert#convert-xml-to-json) - XML to JSON config example is near the end of the `README`
2. [Write a plugin](http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins) based upon [node-xml2json](https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json)?

Answer (score 1):

Reading an xml, pretty simple: use [libxmljs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/libxmljs).

```
var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");  

var xml = grunt.file.read(f);
var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml);
```

Comment: I tried to edit this but I only needed to change "libmlxjs" to "libxmljs" and didn't meet the minimum edit requirements. The link works, but the label is dyslexic.